# HTML Dropdown v/s autocomplete textbox

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

In my project(working on Spring and hibernate) i need to keep around 22 HTML dropdown for a form, each dropdown have around 30,000+ entries every dropdown fetching data from database because of this page loading getting delayed (40+ sec) now i wanted to replace dropdown to similar function one, now i thought to keep autocomplete text box, now i wanted to know major performance issues in HTML Dropdown and  autocomplete textbox or any suggestion or any alternative for this Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a clear case of missing punctuation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think use of autocomplete text box is more beneficial than dropdown.

1. In case of dropdown, data is loaded at once so it get delayed.

   In this case only one request is made to database.
2. In case of autocomplete text box,data will load in exactly required text box.

   So loading time for jsp reduces sharply.
3. (a) For autocomplete text box,there is no need of using any kind of plugin, as one can manage it easily.

   (b) Use simple json format for providing input to text box using ajax.

   (c) Define condition on text box for firing ajax request for showing text like..

   want to get text after typing 3 characters etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jquery chosen plugin.

You can have normal `select box` with the `jquery chosen plugin` applied to that particular select box.

Refer http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-chosen